# IntelliJ does not recognize changing xpath double slash // to single /

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, xpath

Working with IntelliJ Community Edition 2021 using java and selenium.

I built an xpath like this: `//div[@id='trustBank']//li//input[@aria-checked='true']/parent::li//label` and committed my code.

Then I changed the xpath to replace some of the double slashes with single slashes like this:

`//div[@id='trustBank']//li/input[@aria-checked='true']/parent::li/label`

and tried to commit the updated code.

But IntelliJ does not recognize any changes.

Does IntelliJ or java automatically convert double slashes // to single slashes / for me so it doesn't recognize a change?

Comment: Did you save the file? Is the file you edited included in your git repository and not in the `.gitignore` file? Could it be under the "Unversioned Files" section?

Comment: Yes, I saved the file. It is included in my git repo. It's the same file that I had previously committed changes using // in my xpath. I just changed some of them to /.  But it doesn't seem to recognize it. I did see in my Pull Request on github that it seemed to already automatically change those // to /. So it seems some automatic changes are happening.